# Is it possible to connect to multiple BLE devices using web-bluetooth?

Tags: web-bluetooth

The specification for the web-bluetooth is not clear in indicating whether it is possible to connect to multiple devices simultaneously.
The navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice() accepts set of filters and returns a promise when one of the device is selected from the pop-up.
I couldnt find a way to silently connect and listen to all devices matching the given filter.
Does anybody know if this is possible and if yes, could point me to some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, it is possible to connect multiple BLE devices with web-bluetooth. However, it is impossible to connect to a BLE device silently or connect to multiple BLE devices simultaneously. You have to connect to them one by one.

There is a link on web-bluetooth sources discussing about that:
https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/42

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thank you. I put this question on their GitHub issues as well. Hopefully they will add this feature.